# Change view after make ajax call AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am developing a single page application, with help of AngularJS and I'm new to it 
maybe my question is so primitive but at the moment I don't know how to handle it

what I need to do id to open up a pop-up menu after user enters his/her username and password then make a ajax call to Server and if the user is authenticated another view(profile) is displayed.

This is my ajax call

```
   formApp.controller('mainController',function FormCtrl($scope,$http){                                    

           $scope.processForm = function() {
               $http({
                   method  : 'POST',
                   url     : 'login',
                   data    : $.param($scope.formData), 
                   headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
              }).success(function(data){
                        console.log(data);                                                     
                    });

                };
```

And this is the routers and views config :

```
            var formApp = angular.module('formApp', ['ngRoute']);

            formApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'main',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        .when('/profile', {
            templateUrl : 'profile',
            controller  : 'profileController'
        })

            });
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So now in `success` method call route-change: `return $location.path('/profile');`

Also, I guess, you need some service where you will keep user's data.
Also, consider to use ngResource (or similar things) to work with REST backend (and don't keep this logic in controller).

Comment: it doesn't need return without that it works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use modal window and inject controller into it and in resolve make the service call which contains your `$http` request.

see the link for modal window.

[Angular-UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)